# 'model' object has no attribute 'object' - error in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-generic-views, django-errors

I get this error:
`'Searches' object has no attribute 'object'`. I am using the `generic ListView` and I iterate over `object_list` in `template`. That is where the error comes in. My `view` is simple. Just attaching the `model`. All the relevant code is here.

Thanks

urlpatterns:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^create/$','customsearches.views.create_search' , name='create_search'),
                       url(r'^list/$', SearchListView.as_view(template_name='search_list.html'), name='search_list'),
                       )
```

my model:

```
class Searches(models.Model):
    SELLER_CHOICES=(('OWNER','owner'),
                    ('DEALER','dealer'),
                    ('BOTH','both'), )
    #search_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    make = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    keywords = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    max_price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    min_price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    max_year = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    min_year = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    pic_only = models.NullBooleanField()
    search_title_only = models.NullBooleanField()
    owner_dealer_all = models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=SELLER_CHOICES,verbose_name='owner/dealer')
    class Meta:
        #managed = False
        db_table = 'Searches'
        verbose_name_plural = "Searches"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s %s %s-%s" %(self.make,self.model,self.max_year,self.min_year)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('postings.views.detail',args=[model_to_dict(self.object)])
```

view:

```
class SearchListView(ListView):
    model=Searches
```

template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

{% for obj in object_list %}
<p><a href="{{ obj.get_absolute_url }}">{{ obj }}</a></p>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on the line:

```
return reverse('postings.views.detail',args=[model_to_dict(self.object)])
```

`Searches` model doesn't really have an `object` attribute.

[model_to_dict()](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L112) needs a model instance:

```
model_to_dict(self)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: That is indeed where the problem is, but model_to_dict has no business being in that call in the first place.

Comment: @DanielRoseman agreed, it's just a start of the next set of questions/problems.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: I want to pass the the model attributes of this `Searches` model to another `view`, so that I could fetch the relevant postings from a different table. not sure if that is the right way to do. but designs questions are often closed or ignored in SO.